# Homotopy groups of the higher dimensional Hawaiian Earring!

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $S_k$ be the $n$-sphere centered at $(1/k,0,...,0)$ with radius $1/k$, and let $X = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} S_k$. (For $n=1$, this is the standard Hawaiian earring).

I want to show that for $i < n$, $\pi _i (X, x_0) = 0$ (where $x_0$ is the origin). That is, any map from a lower dimensional sphere to $X$ can be homotoped to the constant map.

I have no idea how to proceed with the problem at all. If I know that the image a map $\phi:S^i \to X$ hits only finitely many $S_k$'s, then I can see how all of them can be homotoped individually to the constant map, and since there are finitely many of them, these homotopies can be composed to get a nullhomotopy of $\phi$.

Also if I know that the image of $\phi$ misses a ray from $x_0$ of any small length, we can sort of unfold the ray, to expand to whole of $X$, to get a nullhomotopy of $\phi$. But it's not obvious to me why the image must miss a ray around $x_0$, because we can have space-filling curves.

Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that any path that visits infinitely many spheres also visits $(0,...,0)$ each time it moves from one sphere to another (so infinitely times), as this is the only point any two spheres share. I think you can actually handle infinitely many components just fine, but I am not certain of this.

Comment: This is not at all trivial and I think it cannot be reasonably answered at the level of math.stackexchange. However, your claim was proved in  
Eda, Katsuya, and Kazuhiro Kawamura. "Homotopy and homology groups of the n-dimensional Hawaiian earring." Fundamenta Mathematicae 165.1 (2000): 17-28.  
See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288293404_Homotopy_and_homology_groups_of_the_n-dimensional_Hawaiian_earring.